# Will installing OpenJDK 7 set it automatically as the default jre?

Tags: upgrade, java

I just upgraded to 12.10 and so far it has been the smoothest upgrade ever.

I was surprised to see that the version 6 is still around and was not replaced by Java 7. Is it recommended to install OpenJDK 7?

I was thinking of installed java 7 but from what i read around, it seems that I may have to set it as the default java environment. Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, keeping OpenJDK 6 is a good idea for old Java applets that don't work in OpenJDK 7.

As to making OpenJDK 7 the default, that *may* be relevant to the browser, or installation order - but don't quote me on this, please.